# Team Foundation Server 2012

Tags: tfs, server

I have tried to delete a project in TFS, but the delete iterm is not show,
Please help me to delete the project, thanks very much.
Click here to show the picture    [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp99u.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to delete a default Team in a team project, not a team project (The default Team is not allowed to delete). As I don't have TFS 2012 environment, I'm not sure whether TFS 2012 support deleting a team project on Web UI. You can click on DefaultCollection in the navigation area in the upper left, and check whether you can see a drop down arrow to the left of a team project name when you hover over the name with you mouse. If you could see `Delete` option, then click it to delete a team project on Web UI.

[image]

[image]

If you can not delete a team project from Web UI, you can use the following options:

1. Using the Administration Console, you can delete a team project from a team project collection:

[image]

Details, you can refer to this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/delete-project?view=tfs-2013&tabs=browser#delete-a-project-1

2. You can use the TFSDeleteProject command line tool to delete a team project:

   `TFSDeleteproject [/q] [/force] [/excludewss]/collection:URL TeamProjectName`

Details, you can refer to this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd?view=tfs-2013

Comment: thank you for your help. But  solution 1th, I can not see any drop down , solution , I can not run it, 3th there is an error too, please see 3 piture as below

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvJEi.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84JXs.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCoVE.png

Comment: Do you have correct permission to delete a team project? You must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group or have the Delete team project permission set to Allow. It seems the 3rd screenshot is not you get when you delete from Administration Console.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSgAA.png    I already set permission for the account, that login this UI web, if you have any way other, please guide me

Comment: It seems TFS 2012 doesn't support deleting a team project on Web UI. You need to delete team projects from Administration Console.

Comment: How's the result if you delete team projects from Administration Console?

Comment: I tried delete the project by Administration Console and it seems  I need install config feature, but there are some error occurred , but I have no idea  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCiEW.png

Comment: Your screenshot indicated TFS 2017, not TFS 2012. Did you use the correct version of Administration Console?

Comment: it is amazing !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! it is really problem that I met,now  I can delete any project, thank you so much, have a nice day bro